# Splitting a Python datetime into hour-aligned chunks

Tags: python, datetime, split

I have a `datetime.datetime` instance, `d` and a `datetime.timedelta` instance `td` and am attempting to write a function that will break apart the range `(d, d+td)` into `[(d,x1),(x1,x2),...,(xn,d+td)]` with the `xn` variables all being aligned to the hour.

For example, if

```
d = datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 8, 18, 53, 34)
td = datetime.timedelta(hours=2, minutes=34, seconds=5)
```

I desire a list of

```
[(datetime.datetime(..., 18, 53, 34), datetime.datetime(..., 19, 0, 0)),
 (datetime.datetime(..., 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(..., 20, 0, 0)),
 (datetime.datetime(..., 20, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(..., 21, 0, 0)),
 (datetime.datetime(..., 21, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(..., 21, 27, 39))]
```

Can anyone suggest a nice, Pythonic, means of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [dateutil](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil), you could generate the list using an [rrule](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil#head-470fa22b2db72000d7abe698a5783a46b0731b57):

```
import dateutil.rrule as rrule
import datetime

def hours_aligned(start, end, inc = True):
    if inc: yield start
    rule = rrule.rrule(rrule.HOURLY, byminute = 0, bysecond = 0, dtstart=start)
    for x in rule.between(start, end, inc = False):
        yield x
    if inc: yield end

d = datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 8, 18, 53, 34)
td = datetime.timedelta(hours=2, minutes=34, seconds=5)

for x in hours_aligned(d,d+td):
    print(x)
```

yields

```
2012-09-08 18:53:34
2012-09-08 19:00:00
2012-09-08 20:00:00
2012-09-08 21:00:00
2012-09-08 21:27:39
```

Answer (score 1):

```
chunks = []
end = d + td

current = d
# Set next_current to the next hour-aligned datetime
next_current = (d + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)).replace(minute=0, second=0)

# Grab the start block (that ends on an hour alignment)
# and then any full-hour blocks
while next_current < end:
    chunks.append( (current, next_current) )

    # Advance both current and next_current to the following hour-aligned spots
    current = next_current
    next_current += datetime.timedelta(hours=1)

# Grab any remainder as the last segment
chunks.append( (current, end) )
```

---

The main assumption here is that your initial specified timedelta is not negative. You'll get a single-chunk list `[(x,y)]` where `y < x` if you do that.